# Scroll bar not showing when elements go beyond page view

Tags: css, angular

I am creating a simple recipes app. A list of recipes with there images are shown down the right hand side in individual tiles. The problem I am having is that when the list of recipe tiles goes beyond the browser view, the browser scroll bar does not appear (I have chrome as my browser) and the 3rd recipe tile goes beyond the browser page without being able to scroll down to see the rest of it.

I have found similar questions asked on here and have tried the resolutions provided (such as setting overflow to auto on the container), none of which have resolved my issue.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 280%;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  left: 160px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  color: rgb(90, 205, 250);
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

* {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 265px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 261px;
  right: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 76px;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: 88px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: solid #a84605 1.5px;
  color: hsl(17, 89%, 40%);
  height: 180px;
}

.item-text {
  top: 75px;
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.recipe-container {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h2>Recipes</h2>

<div class="recipe-container">
  <div *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" class="list-item">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" (click)="onRecipeSelected(recipe)">
      <img [src]="recipe.imagePath" alt="{{ recipe.name }}" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading item-text">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding your `recipe-container` class `overflow-y : scroll`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Whilst this showed the scroll bar, it still didn't allow me to scroll.

Comment: did you removed you first mentioned `overflow : auto` from `recipe-container` ?

Comment: I have tried it with overflow : auto and overflow-y : scroll. I have also tried it with just overflow-y : scroll. Neither of which worked

Comment: Please try assign the height and width to `recipe-container` set both as 100% and then check it.

Comment: Still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake give the height and width in pixels.

Comment: How many pixels? 100px on each? That wouldn't be large enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210981/discussion-between-kunal-raut-and-johndev).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you set your height to 'auto' in .recipe-container. Try setting a fixed height of max-height. You could use 'vw' unit to set the height or '%'.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This didn't work i'm afraid